# Can I make my object semi-transparent by adding a PNG texture with alpha cnannel in EEvee?

Tags: uv, eevee-render-engine, transparency

Like it`s possible when Importing images as planes but I want it to work on non-flat object.

Comment: To use alpha in eevee, you must change the blend mode away from _opaque_ in the material settings. Image-as-planes sets it to _alpha-blend_ by default, but for all other materials you must change it yourself. The setting is in the material properties panel.

Comment: thanks, it kinda works but those parts that supposed to be transparent are still more black than transparent, but that`s already something, I guess